# Dusk not working with factories and/or migrations in Homestead

Tags: laravel-5, factory, homestead, laravel-dusk

Using a fresh install of Laravel and dusk, then copying the exact test from the docs for logging in the user, I get an error that the users table doesn't exist.

I don't get any error when using a factory to create a user, but when trying to login as that user, i can see the browser window opening (screenshoots), typing in the creds, then seeing the error that user can't be found.

I see that Dusk tests never ran the migrations.

I change my config/database.php and .env.dusk.local

// config/database.php

```
'connections' => [
         'testing' => [
         'driver' => 'sqlite',
         'database' => database_path('testing.sqlite'),
         'prefix' => '',
          ],
],

`// .env.dusk.local

    APP_URL=http://project.dev
    APP_ENV=testing
    DB_CONNECTION=testing`
```

and ran composer update but the error persist :( my test code:

```
     public function setUp() {
        parent::SetUp();

        factory(Rol::class)->create(['nombre' => 'Administrador']);

        $this->usuario = factory(Usuario::class)->create(['email' => 'correo@ejemplo.com', 'password' => bcrypt('123456'), 'rol_id' => Rol::where('nombre', 'Administrador')->first()->id]);

    }
    /**
     * @tests
     */
    public function loggeo_usuario() {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit(route('login'))
                ->assertSee('Correo')
                ->type('email', $this->usuario->email)
                ->type('#password', '123456')
                ->click('@login-button')
                ->assertSee('Ayuda');
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you post your whole test class?

Comment: Do you use the `DatabaseMigrations` trait in your test class?

Comment: Yep, in my DuskTestCase: use CreatesApplication, DatabaseMigrations;

Comment: Does Dusk create the `testing.sqlite` file when it doesn't exist?